# Meteor 1.4 packages with import

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, package, atmosphere

I want to use imports in my Meteor Atmosphere package. Something like:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
```

But I always get this error:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

I already added `ecmascript` to my package dependencies, but that doesn't help.

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  // Npm.depends({});

  api.versionsFrom('1.4.1');

  api.use([
    'ecmascript',
    'es5-shim',
    'mongo',
    'templating',
    'reactive-var',
    'trever:quill',
    'aramk:quill',
    'aldeed:simple-schema'
  ], 'client');

  api.addFiles([
    'blog.html',
    'blog.css',
    'blog.js',
    'edit-entry.html',
    'edit-entry.css',
    'edit-entry.js',
  ], 'client');

  api.addFiles([
    'blog-server.js',
  ], 'server');
});
```

How can I use ES6 features in Meteors Atmosphere packages?
Is there a sample package file structure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't add the external packages to client AND server:

```
api.use([
    'ecmascript',
    'es5-shim',
    'mongo',
    'templating',
    'reactive-var',
    'momentjs:moment@2.15.2',
    'kadira:flow-router@2.12.1',
    'aldeed:simple-schema@1.5.3',
    'aldeed:collection2@2.10.0',
    'aldeed:autoform@5.8.1',
    'blaze-html-templates',
    'kadira:blaze-layout@2.3.0'
  ], ['client', 'server']);
```